# How to make an HTML table, which is automatically create new row after six item in column?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to make my own site and I don't know how to better dispay images from database. I want to display six images in one row, but the next six item I want to display in second row. How can I make it with this code?

```
<table width="80%">
<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <td>
        <%= product.price %>"> <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %> </td>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Sorry, if this question is really stupid. But I'm just learning and It will help me understand Ruby better.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Enumerable#each_slice` to divide them into sub arrays like so:

```
<table width="80%">
  <% @products.each_slice(6) do |row| %>
    <tr> 
       <% row.each do |product| %>
         <td><%= product.price %>"> <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %> </td>
       <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```